# Evaluate the integral $\int_{c}f(z)dz$ where $C$ is the unit circle enclosing the origin and $f(z)$ is given by $\log(z-z_0)$ with $z_0>1$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Evaluate the integral $\int_{c}f(z)dz$ where $C$ is the unit circle enclosing the origin and $f(z)$ is given by $\log(z-z_0)$ with $z_0>1$.

I don't see how to evaluate this. I have been trying to apply cauchy's integral theorem to conclude that the integral is  $0$, but cannot see how to get around the problem of  $\log(z-z_0)$  not being analytic.

Comment: Which branch of the logarithm?

Comment: the problem does not specify.

Comment: $z_0>1$ has no meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$z\mapsto\log(z-z_0)$ (any branch) is analytic on $D(0,|z_0|)$ hence your integral is $0$.

Comment: but can you help me see why $z\mapsto\log(z-z_0)$  is analytic on $D(0,|z_0|)$ as well as explain the notation "$D(0,|z_0|)$" ?

Comment: $D(a,r)$ is the open disk of center $a\in\mathbb C$ and radius $r>0$. [Since the disk $D(0,|z_0|)-z_0=D(-z_0,|z_0|)$ is a simply connected open subset of $\mathbb C$ not containing $0$, a branch of log can be defined on it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Constructing_branches_via_integration) and is analytic, with $\log'(z)=\frac1z$.